# Issue with Harvest function - UINT256 requires BigNumber

Tags: solidity

Looking for some assistance with a contract that our Dev has left us unable to use.

We're attempting to return funds to the people that submitted them using a multi sig harvest function, however it is returning the following error:

[image: harvest error]

Can anyone please assist? We have 6 Eth to return and are desperately struggling to get around this.

For the above example, we are attempting to return 0.01 ETH.

Contract: 0xc45ea36636A3778D35D6B3226256b942c4A10739

Answer (score 1):

When using the etherscan interface you need to be aware that input values should be denominated in wei (1 eth == 1e18 wei). In above screenshot you attempting to send 0.01 wei which does not exist. Try inputting "10000000000000000" which represent 0.01 ETH in wei.

You can also use this calculator https://eth-converter.com/

Comment: Thank you so much. Attempted the transaction and it proceeds to the next stage. Very appreciated.